# Sharing files over wifi between two windows devices with a uwp app

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

I'm looking for a way to share files (say a text file) between two devices,
I'm making a UWP application and would like to know any frameworks that may help me achieve that

Answer (score 0):

You can use [DataTransferManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.datatransfer.datatransfermanager) to share files between different computers. Of course, this requires the device to turn on the "near sharing" feature. It works through Bluetooth.

If you want to share data via WIFI, then **Wi-Fi Direct** can help you. This is an [example](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/WiFiDirect) of a program provided by Microsoft.

Best regards.

Comment: I looked into them, found a sample called "share target source" through which I can share files with another system if it as nearby sharing option enabled, But what I'm trying to achieve is something at an app-level i.e when I share from my source then the share request will be received by an app on the receiving device, instead of windows kevek

Comment: Hi, you can choose to use the device that sends the file as a server and `StreamWebSocket` to transfer the file to another device.